# Why doesn't my flexbox change its size regarding to box_2?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

guys. Could you help me, please? I just wonder why my flexbox doesn't change its size regaring to box_2. I don't want to change height of flexbox using px but it occurs to me like the only way of how to handle it.

MY HTML and CSS

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
}

.main__block {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid blue;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: green;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
}


.container__element {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="main__block box_1">
        <div class="container__element">Hello1</div>
        <p> A ad aperiam beetur, totam veniam voluptate voluptatum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="main__block box_2">
        <div class="container__element">Hello2</div>
        <span>s tempore vitae! Accusamus aliquam autem consequatur, ea excepturi ipsa nesciunt nisi provident quasi, quos repellat vel veniam veritatis!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad aperiam beetur, totam veniam voluptate voluptatum.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="main__block box_3">
        <div class="container__element">Hello3</div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad aperiam beetur, totam veniam voluptate voluptatum.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

THANK YOU FOR HELP!

Comment: you cannot use percentage that way. You will always have an overflow because you are setting 50% of the initial content height so it will always end bigger if the text is bigger than the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the parent a specific width and height, that's what the children will act upon.
Flex_container has no `width` or `height`.

```
Flex_container{Width:100vw; Height: 100vh;}
```

You can also give `max-width` and `max-height`.

also give the children a background color to see changes.